# Javascript to auto size NAV menu columns

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to style a NAV menu that is created and fed in dynamically by a SAAS CMS. I want the menu to auto resize into any given number of Columns.
For example:
If the NAV overall width is 960px. I want the menu items to resize in to say 5 equal columns. 
Secondly the menu goes two children deep.
So if the top level is parant. this is seen by default on the page. When you hover the Children appear Similar to this site. http://www.laylagrayce.com/ (Ignoring the images in the menu.) I just want it to resize into equal columns.

How can I do this?

Comment: show some code to check

Answer (score 0):

You have heard about responsive websdesign? In this case I think its the onlyest solusion.